# Azure Queue Storage - Mark messages as visible immediately after calling CloudQueue.GetMessages()

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

**Problem:**

I am reading messages from a Azure Storage Queue and then inserting them into a Storage Table using a Worker Role.

I want to read in messages but only process them if there are at least 100 (this is to optimize the Storage Table batch insert which is occurring).  If there are less than 100 messages, then I want to cancel the message processing and make them immediately visible on the queue again for the next queue read.

**Question:**

Is it possible to mark a message which has just been read by `CloudQueue.GetMessages(...)` as visible without having to wait for the timeout to expire?

**Code:** (in WorkerRole.cs)

```
public override void Run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var messages = queue.GetMessages(100);

        if (messages.Count() >= 100)
        {
            // This will process, insert into a table, and delete from the queue
            ProcessMessages(messages);
        }
        else
        {
            //!!! MARK MESSAGES AS VISIBLE ON THE QUEUE
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the queue's `ApproximateMessageCount' property (details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudqueue.approximatemessagecount.aspx)), which will give you a rough idea how many messages are waiting in the queue.

Also: you can set a message's invisibility timeout to something small (maybe 5-10 seconds?). After that period, the message becomes visible again. You can also modify invisibility timeout to something shorter after you read it.

Just remember that reading from the queue counts as a transaction, as does updating messages (e.g. updating invisibility timeout).

Waiting for 100 messages may be a non-optimal optimization. Oh, and `GetMessages()`(details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758360.aspx)) is limited to 32 messages, so it doesn't make sense to wait for 100. Also: Transactions are really, really cheap (a penny per 100K transactions). I don't necessarily see the value here.

Comment: I can't use ApproximateMessageCount() because another instance of the Worker Role may pick up the messages before GetMessages() is called.  

Ah, I didn't realise there was a limit of 32.  

The more items included in a batch insert, the faster the 'write' time is per item.  Because I'm dealing with millions/billions of records per day, I need to optimise to the max.

Comment: I agree with David re value. What are you trying to optimise with storage batch inserts? If it is cost, be very careful, you may be prematurely optimising for cost. Optimisation for cost, unless it is with compute, will seldom save much.

Comment: I am not optimising for cost, I just found that performing singular inserts would never achieve max insert rates on a partition (up to 2000/s per partition).  By batch inserting entities, I could achieve a much higher rate.  As far as I understand, batch inserting was one of the biggest performance breakthroughs with the Storage Client Library v2.0.

Comment: If you read up to 32 existing queue items, and write them as batch, you'll have the opportunity to go beyond 2000/sec. But also think about your schema and storing data across multiple partitions rather than targeting a single partition.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the expire time to 0.0.  That will hopefully do the trick.